# Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

How to upload metadata in lookup type column in SharePoint document library using PowerAutomate flow?

When you click button in PowerApps the flow should be triggered and output should be updated in SharePoint library?

I have tried for this query solution all columns in the library metadata will be updated but except one column. It is a lookup datatype column. I don't know how to create flow for this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details on this issue.